# Django Mezzanine framework - won't let me embed videos to blog post

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I can't get Mezzanine Framework for Django to accept embedding videos into my blog posts. I tried using the `video` tag of the `rich text editor`, tried editing the `html` code and inserting the `iframe` YouTube provides me, but with no success. Once I hit save, Mezzanine strips the code right out, like it's never been there before.

I googled a lot and stumbled upon [this article from the documentation](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/configuration.html#richtext-filter-level) which says:

> Setting the filtering level to no filtering, will disable all filtering, and allow any code to be entered by staff members, including script tags.
>
> Choices: High: 1, Low (allows video, iframe, Flash, etc): 2, No filtering: 3

Then I went on and updated my `settings.py` and added the variable `RICHTEXT_FILTER_LEVEL=3` (no filtering). Restarted `Apache` and again, without success.

You guys are my last resort.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It actually needs to be changed in the admin. Log in to your admin, then in the top left hover over 'Site', then click on 'Settings'. Scroll down and you should see a setting called 'Rich text filter level'. Change this setting to low and then save. You should be able to embed your video now.

Comment: This is the right way. I was in a hurry and then changed the very mezzanine code to accept iframe element. Not that I recomend that. I recomend doing it the right way showed in this answer. Thanks.